# Editing buttons missing (occasionally)

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noticed that on several occasions over the last day, when I open a new editing box, the buttons on the top row are missing. They aren't invisible, just *gone*. It also seems to disable the Ctrl+I and Ctrl+B shortcut keys.

[image]

This seems to be replicable if you open the editing box, then cancel/save it, *then open it again*. It can be fixed by reloading.

**FYI: Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 - Windows 8.1 Pro.**

Comment: I can repro this on Edge 25.10586.0.0 and Firefox 46.0.1, both on Windows 10 Pro. And there's no error messages in the Javascript console

Comment: Possibly related to this; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/were-updating-jquery-to-1-12-4-tomorrow?cb=1

Comment: @JasonBaker - I can also replicate it on Samsung Internet for Android 4.0.20-17

Answer (score 4):

I have rolled back the fix we deploy earlier today.  This should resolve the issues you hit today.

Comment: When you "fix" it again, can you add a button that randomly inserts a picture of Buffy the Vampire Slayer into the body of the answer?

Answer (score 3):

We're investigating a bug where [the opposite happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284896/editor-toolbar-bug) - people getting a lot of additional toolbars and pushed out a fix for that earlier today. We'll check to see if this is now causing the opposite problem, apologies for that.

Just to help us troubleshoot this better: Are you behind a proxy (e.g. corporate network) or directly connected to the internet?

Also, did this just happen today, or did it happen before?

Comment: It's just today, I think. I'm directly connected to the internet, not through a firewall.